# CriteriaBuilder.and & CriteriaBuilder.or, how-to?

Tags: jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I'm trying to change the following HQL to use JPA Criteria:

```
select distinct d from Department d 
left join fetch d.children c 
where d.parent is null 
and (
    d.name like :term 
    or c.name like :term
    ) 
order by d.name
```

`Department` has a `Set<Department>` of children.

Criteria:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Department> c = cb.createQuery(Department.class);
Root<Department> root = c.from(Department.class);
root.fetch("children", JoinType.LEFT);
Path<Department> children = root.join("children", JoinType.LEFT);
c.orderBy(cb.asc(root.get("name")));
c.distinct(true);
c.where(cb.isNull(root.get("parent")));
String param = "%" + "term" + "%";
cb.and(cb.like(root.<String> get("name"), param));
cb.or(cb.like(children.<String> get("name"), param));

TypedQuery<Department> tq = getEntityManager().createQuery(c);
departments = tq.getResultList();
```

I know it can be a bit terse, however, the HQL returns 24 and Criteria version 28. I think I'm not handling:

```
and (x = y OR z = y)
```

correctly. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Here's the where clause of your JPQL query:

```
where d.parent is null 
and (
    d.name like :term 
    or c.name like :term
    )
```

The where clause contains two predicates:

```
d.parent is null
```

and

```
(d.name like :term 
 or c.name like :term)
```

The second predicate is an `or` containing two predicates:

```
d.name like :term
```

and

```
c.name like :term
```

So you need the same structure in your criteria query:

```
Predicate orClause = 
    cb.or(cb.like(root.<String>get("name"), param),
          cb.like(children.<String>get("name"), param));

c.where(cb.isNull(root.get("parent")),
        orClause);
```

Comment: Thanks for this as I too was looking for this.